# Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my code

```
var finalResults = (from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<DateTime>("PrintTime") is DBNull
```

where `PrintTime` is a column in my `Sql Server 2008 r2` database, its type is `datetime` and it is **nullable**

I got this exception:

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a
>   nullable type.

Could you help please?

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: `DateTime` is a `struct` making it non-nullable. `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` is a wrapper which makes it nullable. Do the math.

Comment: @Servy I already tried DBnull.value and had the same problem

Comment: You need to cast using `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?`, and then compare it against `null`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli That's not doing what the error message is telling you to do.  It is very explicit about what you need to do.

Comment: or you can use `DataRow[] myResultSet = results.Select("[PrintTime] is null");`

Comment: @Servy if it was so obvious which type to use that was nullable, do you really think they'd ask for help? thanks for a worthless comment.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus Considering the user accepted an answer that functionally says the same thing, apparently they *are* the kind of person who'd ask this question without actually reading the error message.  Apparently *you* decided to criticize my comment without even looking at the answer to see that the author really did miss something so obvious.

Comment: gosh you're so smug and smart and such a genius, we really value your arrogance here.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus The fact that you think it's "genius" level to actually read an error message says more about you than it does about me.  That I expect other people to be literate, rather than thinking that they need my help for something so difficult is literally the opposite of arrogance.  You, being the one who thinks that this person is so incompetent that they need your help to do this for them, is the one who is acting arrogantly.

Comment: @Servy define facetious. literate? really?? the official documentation for mapping CLR parameters itself shows the .NET data type DateTime as nullable... you saying, "hey read the error" that doesn't really help anyone. the fact you were on here 30 seconds after i posted a reply to your comment from almost 2 years ago and that you felt the right to defend it speaks a lot more than you criticizing me for deeming your comments irrelevant. obviously you don't know anything about helping people to understand other than your "DIY" attitude."

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus When you reply to a comment of mine I get a notification.  If I wasn't specifically notified, I'm sure I'd never have seen the comment.  Telling someone to read the error message wouldn't be helpful if they actually read the error message and it didn't contain all the information they needed to solve their problem.  When they just couldn't be bothered to read it when it *does* tell them everything they need to know, then it's an *entirely* helpful statement, as it's giving them everything they need to solve their problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=VS.90).aspx) supports nullable types, so use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`:

```
var finalResults = from r in results.AsEnumerable()
                   let printTime = r.Field<DateTime?>("PrintTime")
                   where !printTime.HasValue
                   select r;
```

Comment: as always, the best one in datatable issues :P +1 will accept when the system allows

Comment: could you check my new question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514603/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-int64-to-a-known-managed-provider-na I appreciate your help and support